# .htaccess 301 redirect resolving to https// (not http://)

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

https://www.rawgymsdublin.com
resolves to 
http://https//www.rawgyms.com/

syntax in the .htaccess file is:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.rawgyms.com/
```

I just updated the name servers to this host on Friday so it is only recently swapped. Can anyone tell me is the syntax wrong, or is there a better method to 301 redirect?

edit: added image of network traffic in the browser

[image: network traffic in the browser]

Comment: The redirect directive itself looks OK providing this `.htaccess` file is for the `rawgymsdublin.com` domain only? Is that all you have in the `.htaccess` file? Check the network traffic in the browser to confirm what redirect(s) are happening. "resolves to" - presumably you mean "redirects to"? The DNS `A` records for this host are returning different results on each request?

Comment: The A records are in amazon AWS, maybe that is causing an issue, but I thought if the name servers were updated that it would bypass AWS A records?

Comment: I'm getting a `X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront` header when I try that URL. Is it possible that the redirect is configured in cloudfront and never reaches your server?

Comment: Seems to be sporadic DNS issues? The redirect appeared to work once (correctly) for me - after some delay - then it failed to connect entirely? Maybe you're currently working on the issue?

Comment: @MrWhite I also have this in the file: AddHandler php73-script .php .php5

also, yes I disabled CloudFront, might take 15 mins to complete

Comment: That’s updated now, is it working for you? I think my cache won’t show an updated version so I can’t tell what it’s really doing. Thank you.

Comment: It still seems a bit intermittent for me, but it is "working". However, there is a second redirect that removes the `www` subdomain. ie. `rawgyms.com` would seem to be the canonical domain, not `www.rawgyms.com` (as stated in your initial redirect).

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean by "rawgyms.com would seem to be the canonical domain", do you mean I should remove the www in the .htacess file?